# What should I do when system tables of PostgreSQL are damaged?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

My computer shut down because of power failier. And an error occurred in the log after I restarted the database:

```
ERROR: invalid page header in block 27073 of relation base/263742/11768.
```

I got to know that damaged relation is 'pg_class' by executing the command:

```
  oid2name -H 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres -f 11768

  From database "postgres":
  Filenode  Table Name
----------------------
     11768    pg_class
```

So, what should I do to recover my database as soon as possible? Thank you.

Comment: Can you connect to your database ? An approach would be log-in, pg_dump what you want to keep, create a new database and import the database dump. All depend son size, available disk space etc.

Comment: doesn't pg_dump read from pg_class?..

Comment: @Mokadillion I just found that the database cannot be backuped with 'pg_dump' if pg_class is damaged.

Comment: @VaoTsun Didn't know, thanks.  - Can you connect ? perhaps copy to file of what you need, per table could take a while ?